# Archive view block on User Profile page

Tags: 7, users

How can we put a archive view block on user profile page, and this archive views should only display the archives of the user.

Lets take an example, my username is "MyUser" and i am view a profile of other user ie "SomeUser".

Then how can we put a archive view block in profile page of "SomeUser" where it should displays the contents/ list of stories or articles he/she posted.

Do we need to do UI method over archive view block or need to write a seperate code for this.

Comment: How are you maintaining the state of archive?

Comment: I believe in Months..

Comment: I have installed a module "Archive"